# I saw the table creation operation in the IDEA console, but I don't see the table in the H2 page

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

Below is the entity code,We can see the SQL creation statements for the relevant tables in the Idea console.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MED_PGW")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MedPgwEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "key_field")
    private String keyField;

    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date createTime;


    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Date updateTime;

}
```

[idea console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/souA0.png)

```
2024-02-19 16:53:39.261 [] [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists customer CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists med_pgw CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table customer (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table med_pgw (key_field varchar(255) not null, body varchar(255), create_time timestamp, update_time timestamp, primary key (key_field))
```

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9QBB.png)

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    druid:
#      url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
      username: med
      password: med
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
    path: /h2-console
```

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/see5v.png)

```
Saved Settings:Generic H2 (Server)
Setting Name:Generic H2 (Server)
Driver Class:org.h2.Driver
JDBC URL:jdbc:h2:mem:test
User Name:med
Password:med
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfQZb.png)

I saw the table creation operation in the IDEA console, but I don't see the table in the H2 page.

I hope to see the information of the created tables on this page.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @seenukarthi ok,Thank you for your reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing druid jar package, just import the jar package.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

or modify application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    username: med
    password: med
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay sometime, the browser might cache the H2 console page. Try clearing your browser cache or open the H2 console in an incognito private browsing window,

and also try to configure in application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.druid.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.druid.username=med
spring.datasource.druid.password=med
spring.datasource.druid.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Comment: Still no effect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).